# Rearrange visual order of 2 divs with floats and negative margin

Tags: css

In a current project, we would like the navigation above the header on small screens, and for those 2 divs to switch order visually in tablet screen sizes @media (min-width: 20em) for example. I remember being able to do this with some crafty use of floats and negative margins, but I don't remember how I did it. *note that I have box sizing on everything and assume that I have a full reset. [HERE is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/gH5KX/)

HTML

```
<nav>nav</nav>

<header>header</header>
```

CSS

```
nav, header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f06;
}

header {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}



@media (min-width: 20em) {

  nav {
    /* ? */
  }

  header {
    /* ? */ 
  }

} /* ===================== */
```

THANKS! dw c/o nouveau

Comment: So what you need to do is to make them look like header on top of nav, right?

Comment: Yes. I want the nav on top (because I'm having it animate on mobile button click) and I want it above the header so that it slides down, however - in tablet sizes - I want the nav below and always visible. I just want to flip the order visually. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can always do it by `position: absolute`, but I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: You are correct on both accounts. My goal is to keep everything 100% fluid. What if the header text length changes - changing it's height etc... Gotta keep it squishy. Especially if you are trying to build something reusable like a WP theme. Most "responsive" themes break as soon as you change anything. Trying not to be part of that problem.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'd suggest taking a look at this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/</strike>

I feel embarrassed for suggesting that link actually. The appropriate link was [css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox) and this is also a decent one  weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox, both discussing flexbox.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already have a screen dependent style sheet built right in above via an @media rule. I see that you have 1 point and that you must be new. Technically this is a suggestion and should be a comment as opposed to an answer. Some people are sticklers and I wouldn't want you getting down-voted right off the bat! Thanks though!

Comment: I feel embarrassed for suggesting that link actually. The appropriate link was http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and this is also a decent one http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/, both discussing flexbox. Unfortunately I could not comment with such low reputation, which I found out after posting that answer.

Comment: Oh yeah... I forgot about that little hurdle. I'll check those out.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using CSS3 flexbox, which should be available wherever media queries are available.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>nav</nav>
    <header>header</header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}

nav, header {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2em;
}

nav {
    background-color: #f06;

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
}

header {
    background-color: yellow;

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 20em) {
    nav {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        box-ordinal-group: 2;
    }

    header {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        box-ordinal-group: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super great, however - I'm still targeting IE 8 and 9. The main reason I'm asking this question is because I've done this in the past and I just can't remember how to do it. It's kinda hacky, but would work perfectly in this instance... maybe I could flip the way I have it in the DOM so that it is progressively enhanced instead of gracefully degrading... but then opera mini is still left out... I think the -margin thing is going to be more cross compatible.